# Provision classic cloud service via ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

In one of our project, we are trying to automate deployment of cloud components on Azure. For majority of components *(basically all ARM components like Redis, Service bus, App Service etc.)* we were able to achieve it using ARM templates and Powershell script.

However, we are stuck at **Cloud Service (classic)** component. Cloud service component contains only WebRole in it and no VM needs to be provisioned.

We can go via classic deployment model i.e. using ASM commands in power shell. But since, ARM model supports provisioning and deployment from azure portal so I was wondering ARM REST API's must have out of box support for this component as well. I try to figure out but couldn't find any related documentation to it.

---

### What I have tried so far

Azure template (AzureDeploy.json)

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
         {
            "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
        }
    ]
}
```

Powershell script:

```
Param(
    [string] $ResourceGroupLocation = 'South India',
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'FreeTrial',
    [string] $TemplateFile = 'AzureDeploy.json'
)

$TemplateFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $TemplateFile))

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                   -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                   -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                   -Force -Verbose
```

If I try to execute the above script, execution gets stuck at Checking deployment for an hour or so and have to manually kill the script execution.
[image: Script execution].

---

However, if I ran following command in power shell, it succesfully creates a resource in portal:

> New-AzureRmResource -Location "South India" -ResourceName
>   "cloudsmplservice" -ResourceType
>   "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames" -ResourceGroupName "FreeTrial"

But I do not understand what's an issue with ARM template approach. Can someone please direct me to the problem in first approach?

---

**Addendum:**

I found a strange behaviour. If I hardcode the resource name value in the resource definition OR pass it when powershell prompt for it, deployment works fine.

However, if I set some default Value for parameter OR pass it via parameter file, its not working.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "cloudName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "cloudsrvc"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('cloudName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Addendum2:**

Seems like some powershell configuration issue. Will report it to Azure team with more details. So, far was able to reproduce it with simple steps:

1. Created a fresh VM in azure.
2. Imported AzureRM modules.
3. Try to provision cloud service with default value template. (Stuck as mentioned)
4. Try to provision now by passing the parameter from powershell. (Worked fine)
5. Now try again with default value template. (Worked fine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will recommend you to validate your Cloud Service ARM Template from the **Template Deployment** in the Azure portal.

I am able to deploy a bare metal Cloud Service using the template below and the deployment is successful within seconds.

You can also "reverse engineer" the Cloud Service ARM Template by clicking on the Automation option when try to create a new Cloud Service from the Azure portal.

I didn't see the problem in automating Cloud Service by the ARM Template approach.

**Note:**

I have deployed this in **South India** location and it works.

**Addendum:**

I have deployed the template as below using your PowerShell script and it works as well.

Azure PowerShell version is **4.3.1 (August 2017)**.

Screenshot as below.
[image]

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-11-01",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Addendum 2:**

Try with template with default param values and the deployment is also working successful.

Note: I notice your api version is older and the api version for my cloud service is **2016-11-01**

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I used the same template but same error again :( 
Did you use same powershell script as provided above OR something else? Also, could it be possible that to use classic resources, I need to import some package or something in powershell?

Comment: Did you get the same error from Template Deployment in Azure portal?

Comment: What Azure PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: No it worked fine with Template deployment in Azure portal.

Comment: Azure powershell version is 4.2.1

Comment: I have updated my answer by testing with your PowerShell script and it works.

Comment: Updating the powershell version to 4.3.1 also didn't work for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152631/discussion-between-juvchan-and-rohit-vats).

Comment: I found an issue that why its working for you and not for me because I was passing the parameter value via parameter file. I have updated the question as per the observation. Can you please check?

Comment: Okay when I try I enter the Parma values when prompted by PowerShell, will.help.to check tmw

Comment: Now working fine for me as well with original posted template. Updated question with more findings. However, your answer helped me in tracking down a workaround. Hence, marking it as an answer.

Comment: Glad that my answer has helped you

Answer (score 1):

We also could use the REST API to do that,I test it with fiddler.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{cloudservicename}?api-version=2016-04-01
```

[image]

**Note**: please make sure that your subcription support to create the cloudservice in that location. If it is not supported, we will get the following error.

> The location constraint is not valid

Comment: Thanks Tom for a workaround. However, I am looking for a reason that via ARM tempalte approach is not working?

Comment: I also can repro the issue with default value in the deploy file,  If it is possible, please have a try to use  command with parameter **TemplateParameterFile**  `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "group" -TemplateFile "deployment.json" -TemplateParameterFile "parameter.json" `. We could give our [feedback](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues) to azure team. More info about `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` please refer to [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-4.3.1)

Comment: Thanks Tom, even default value template is working fine. Please refer to the update in question. Will report to azure team with more logs. Thanks for your help :)