# What are the ARM Template equivalents for these csdef and cscfg values

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cloud-services, azure-worker-roles, azure-rm-template

I currently have a code base that has a number of classic Azure cloud service worker roles. In the long run, I want to migrate this entire infrastructure to Azure Service Fabric, but as a first step, I'd like to update the deployment model to make use of ARM templates.

[I found another answer that seems to have a barebones ARM template to deploy a Cloud Service (classic) component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824342/provision-classic-cloud-service-via-arm-template), but I'm unsure how to translate that to my own application.

Specifically, how/where would I define the following tags & attributes from my worker role's [csdef file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/schema-csdef-file):

```
WorkerRole (name, vmsize)
startup tasks (command line, execution context, task type, task variables)
configuration settings
certificates
localresources
```

and it's [cscfg files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/schema-cscfg-file):

```
Serviceconfiguration  (name, osFamily, osVersion)
Role (name)
Instances (count)
ConfigurationSettings (and all the setting name/values under it)
certificates
```

Comment: You can take a look at [Guide to converting Web and Worker Roles to Service Fabric stateless services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service).

Comment: I am not looking to convert them to Service Fabric stateless services at this time

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately today there is no way to deploy PaaS v1 Cloud Services deployments (web/worker roles) using ARM templates.  The other SO post you reference is only deploying the cloud service (the logic parent of the production and staging slots), but not deploying the actual service itself to one of the production or staging slots.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deploy your classic cloud service using ARM:

- The package link is the uri of your `*.cspkg` file.
- The configuration link is the uri of your `*.cscfg` file.

I would suggest you to upload your files to a blob storage before deploying the template.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [{
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames"
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('slotName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('name')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "deploymentLabel": "[parameters('deploymentLabel')]",
        "packageLink": {
          "Uri": "[parameters('packageLink')]"
        },
        "configurationLink": {
          "Uri": "[parameters('configurationLink')]"
        },
        "deploymentOptions": "[parameters('deploymentOptions')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me know if you need more information such as adding a cert.

Comment: Have you actually done this yourself? I have yet to find any examples online, and most sources from Microsoft I've seen suggest this isn't possible.

Comment: I'm just getting around to testing this now. Do you have a link handy that describes valid values for deploymentOptions, and dependsOn? Also, does name refer to the name of the cloud service I'm deploying to?

Comment: @BobbyA, If you create a cloud service manually from the portal, rather than clicking `create`, click `automation options` then it will generate this kind of ARM for you.

Comment: I could use help referencing a cert :)